# Find leading 1s in the binary number

Tags: c, binary, byte

everyone,

I am new in C and I try to understand the work with bytes, binary numbers and another important thing for the beginner.

I hope someone can push me in the right direction here.

For example, I have a 32- bits number 11000000 10101000  00000101 0000000 (3232236800). 
I also assigned each part of this number to separate variables as a=11000000  (192), b = 10101000 (168), c =00000101 (5) d = 0000000 (0). I am not sure if I really need this.

Is there any way to find the last 1 in the number and use this location to calculate the number of leading 1s?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Finding the last 1 in `10101000` doesn't tell you how many other 1's there is (just how many there *could* be). Anyway, for a beginner this is pretty unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the bitposition of the first leading 1 by this formula:

```
floor(ln(number)/ln(2))
```

Where "floor()" means rounding down.
For counting the number of consecutive leading ones (if I get the second part of your question correctly) I can only imagine a loop.

Note 1:
The formula is the math formula for "logarithm of number on the base of 2".
The same works with `log10()`. Basically you can use any logarithm (i.e. to any base) this way to adapt to a different base.

Note 2:
It is of course questionable whether this formula is more efficient than search from MSB downwards with a loop. It could be with good FPU support. It probably is not for 8bit values. Double check in case you are out to speed optimise.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you arrived at this formula?

Comment: @J...S Thanks for your comment, I improved the answer because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not a C expert, but here's the Python code I came up with:

```
num_ones = 0
while integer > 0:
    if integer % 2 == 1:
        num_ones += 1
    else:
        num_ones = 0
    integer = integer >> 1
```

Basically, I count the number of continuous 1's by bit shifting the given integer.
A zero would reset the counter.